# alternatives to the ordinary select dropdown (styling)

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can it be possible to make a select dropdown where you can style the input as you like?

can you make something out of div elements? and how can you then "tab" between the inputs (ie. tabindex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI team is currently in the process of building out the official Selectbox code for the 1.9 release.  In preparation, the Filament Group has done quite a bit of work to research, design, and code the project.  It's currently available from them and working quite well, supporting ThemeRoller, icons, selectgroups, and more.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: update (2014): it seems like contributions to this project have been very low in 2013 (see [https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/graphs/contributors](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/graphs/contributors)

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest this great jQuery plugin:
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/

It generates nice standard HTML and also takes care about keyboard navigation. It has very good usability and is fully unobstrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Generally an ordered or unordered list is used to simulate a drop down, but it takes a lot of code to reproduce the arrow, letter key and  and tab key handling of a select-not to mention including the selected value(s) in a form submissionm.

Modern browsers allow styling of individual option elements, which may be more suited to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

[FogBugz](https://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/try/?fccmp=_tryfb_nav), a stackoverflow product, uses a nice one:

[image]

Comment: Why choosing a trial product if there are many (many!) free alternatives very well done?

Comment: No... this is not a jquery plugin. They have implemented their own select in the product, the point was to show the feature not the product which is a bug tracking software.

Comment: looks pretty ugly to me if you ask me - and what's the point of simply showing how their implementation look like? i might as well provide a design as an answer..!